# how should i write if statement to redirect to two differnt pages(ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two different pages that both have the create page form, but I want the first redirect to the index page of this controller and the second redirect to the current page.

Is there a way to use a conditional if-else statement instead of writing two functions which is stupid.

I am using rails 5.1.7 and ruby 2.6.3

the first function:

```
  def create
    @page_hotspot_external = PageHotspotExternal.new(page_hotspot_external_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page_hotspot_external.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page_hotspot_external, notice: 'Page hotspot external was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page_hotspot_external }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page_hotspot_external.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

the second function

```
  def createExternalHotspot
    @page_hotspot_external = PageHotspotExternal.new(page_hotspot_external_params)
    @user_project = UserProject.find_by(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @page_hotspot_external.save
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page_hotspot_external }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page_hotspot_external.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What I'm looking for:

```
  def create
    @page_hotspot_external = PageHotspotExternal.new(page_hotspot_external_params)
    @user_project = UserProject.find_by(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @page_hotspot_external.save
        if xxxxxxxxxxx  //if statement 
          format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)}
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page_hotspot_external }
        else
          format.html { @page_hotspot_external}
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page_hotspot_external }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page_hotspot_external.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: The problem with the code above is just that you are missing an `end` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @page_hotspot_external.save
        format.html {
            if (params[:request_from] == "simple_create") # your custom logic, may be you can add this param in your form that you are sending to this action
                redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Redirecting with condition 1'
            elsif (params[:request_from] == "createExternalHotspot") # another custom logic
                redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Redirecting with condition 2'
            else
                redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Redirecting with else default'
            end
        }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page_hotspot_external }
    end
end
```

You can use any condition you like, for example.

> 1- You can send the `params[:request_from]` from your form if you want
>   to differentiate between both forms. For this you have to add hidden
>   field in second form.
>
> ```
> <%= hidden_field_tag :custom_param, 'createExternalHotspot' %>
> ```
>
> 2- Use your own logic in the if condition to differentiate the request
>
> 3- You can also make logic based on the `request.referer` it contains
>   the url from where the request is coming.

Hope I was able to understand your question. If not please add your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @page_hotspot_external.save
    format.html do
      condition ? redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path) : @page_hotspot_external
    end
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page_hotspot_external }
  else
...
```

Comment: what is the condition may I ask?

Comment: Is there any difference in in creating a `PageHotspotExternal` between `create` action and `createExternalHotspot`?

Comment: there is no difference for the create function , the only difference is that the current page is different.  For example the first page is loaclhost:3000/editor , the second page is localhost:3000/project_pages

Comment: so i want the first page remain the same page and second page redirect to page_hotspot_external/index      Thank you !

Comment: You want one action with 2 redirect options correct? what is the condition base on that you want to switch between the redirect options?

Comment: @jimmyjiang can you please tell what is your condition? or you don't know what condition will be added?